# Results returned by socket.recvfrom()

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.5, raw-sockets, recvfrom

I have this simple code in python-3.5 :

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
raw_data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65536)
```

recvfrom() returns data received on the socket in raw_data variable and a tuple in addr variable.

This returned tuple (addr) has 5 elements in it and I can't find the meaning of the different elements.

addr[0] contains the name of the interface on which raw_data was received.

addr[1] contains the Ethertype received.

addr[4] contains the layer 2 address of the sender (as far as I understand).

What are the values contained in elements addr[2] and addr[3]?

Comment: `ntohs(3)` - is that right?

Comment: ntohs(3) means "capture all packets" on the raw socket. It's the value of ETH_P_ALL constant.

Comment: That value is in host byte order. Should it not be `htons(3)`?

Comment: I have to check. It's works well like this. ntohs(3) should be equivalent to htons(0x0003).

Comment: This constant, defined in if_ether.h is declared as : #define ETH_P_ALL 0x0003 /* Every packet (be careful!!!) */

Comment: All network constants are in host byte order.

Answer (score 0):

The third one is somehow related to a sender address you see:

```
('eth0', 2048, 4, 1, b'RT\x00\x96\x9d\x16')
('eth0', 2054, 1, 1, b'\x00\x10t"\x82|')
('eth0', 2048, 0, 1, b'l;k`g0')
```